# iPhone X simulator bug when turn on "color off-screen rendered"?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I found a strange behavior on iPhone X simulator:

When I turn on `color off-screen rendered` option in simulator, the whole screen is rendered yellow (indicating the whole screen is rendered off-screen), even though the root viewcontroller of the window is a 
bare viewcontroller with white background.

When I run the same app on iPhone 8 simulator and turn `color off-screen rendered` option on, only the status bar of the screen is rendered yellow.

Anyone got an idea what is the cause of the difference?

Comment: Possibly a bug (and thus worth [reporting to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) even if it might not be). Note that for rendering performance profiling / debugging, you're probably better off testing against an actual device (using Instruments to turn on things like overlay colors for off screen rendering) anyway.

Comment: @rickster Seems it is an iPhone X simulator issue. I can't reproduce the bug on iPhone X device with core animation instrument. Thanks!

Comment: Please do file a bug on this.

Comment: @russbishop I have report this bug on bugreport.apple.com  . The problem ID is 36678995.

Comment: I assume it is caused by the way Springboard handles app switching transitions which is more sophisticated compared to normal iOS devices. It's annoying and has to be fixed by Apple.